# COUNT all "P" from a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a presence row in a sheet (Google or MS Excel, does not really matter), having values "A" or "P" for each name.

I need to count how many "P" I have, to make the cell RED if there is any "P" in that row.

```
 Name 1 2 3 4
______________
 John A A P A
 Mary P P P A
 Suzy P P P P
 Dick A A A A
```

So I need red cell to Dick...

How to count the "P" symbols from a given row?

**PS. Some restrictions:**

- I need the whole line starting with, say the second column "to the end", like `B2:B`?
- Is there a way to have an universal formula? say `=COUNTIF(B2:B, "P") > 0` to became `=COUNTIF(B+ROW():B, "P") > 0`

Comment: The row `Dick` is the only one without a P, but it sounds like you want that one to be red? Can you confirm? Have you attempted any conditional formatting to achieve this?

Comment: conditional formatting

Comment: @Jonno, we suppose P is not for pussy )

Comment: @Jonno as for the question, I read it now, it seems I wanted the Dick to be Red, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets for a red dick witout p.:

```
range:   A1:A4
formula: =COUNTIF(B1:B; "P")=0
```

[image]

Or generic for all the A column (`A:A`) count all columns starting from second column (`B2:1`)

[image]

fixed formula not to include empty cells:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B1:1; "P")=0; NOT(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(B1:1)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$E2,"P")>0
```

Applying to:

```
=$B$2:$E$5
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Google Spreadsheets:

```
Name    Hidden  1   2   3   4
John    1       A   A   P   A
Mary    3       P   P   P   A
Suzy    4       P   P   P   P
Dick    0       A   A   A   A
```

You set the dick name column via Format - Conditional Formatting - Custom formula is `=B5=0` e.g., then you copy the first Dick column to other rows and change the names or set it the same way for other rows.
Then, you can hide the Hidden column.
In Excel there is conditional formatting as well, can't remember where exactly, you can also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>V</kbd> just formatting/text), don't know if this is possible in Google Spreadsheets.

EDIT: the hidden column content is `=COUNTIF(C5:F5,"P")` for Dick, similarly for other rows.